# Installing requirements.txt inside of a folder in a VScode dev container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I am using Microsoft's template for Python dev-container
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python

and it worked as it should, I made a small change to the structure. I added a folder called "project1" and moved the requirements.txt file to that folder.

When I update the .devcontainer file with this setting:

```
{
...
"postCreateCommand": "pip install -r subject-selection/requirements.txt"
...
}
```

It fails, saying it cannot find the file. What am I doing wrong?

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── data
└── subject-selection
    ├── Dataset Analysis.ipynb
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── analysis_utils.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── analysis_utils.py
    ├── download-subjects.py
    ├── out
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── run-placement-analysis.sh
```

Comment: Can you give more info on your setup please, like a reference folder structure, a screenshot from the packages in VS code or something like that? Can you reproduce the problem somewhere to share the link?

Comment: I have a similar structure in my project and the postCreateCommand works as it should.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `postCreateCommand` runs from the location `/bin/sh`, so in your case it's looking for the file '/bin/sh/subject-selection/requirements.txt'. You probably want something like this instead:

```
"postCreateCommand": "pip install -r /workspaces/subject-selection/requirements.txt"
```